# How to apply a pagebreak for a HTMLCell with dynamic height in TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a site where u can print a sheet via TCPDF containing various information.
Most of this information are tables for which i found it quite easy to write a pagebreak myself. I could not use the AutoPageBreak method with these aswell because the HTMLCell seems to start in my header in case of an automatic pagebreak (I generate the Y-value dynamically through getY()). So i wrote a simple pagebreak and it works just fine with an iteration of HTMLCells.
The problem is now i need to have a pagebreak for just one HTMLCell that is displaying messages such as E-Mails that are saved on the site. so i need to kind of split the HTMLCell into 2 in case of a pagebreak or have it not to ignore my header.

I have searched for this quite a lot and didn't seem to find an answer.
I've seen a post by Nicola Asuni where he wrote that it would work with transactions but i don't quite see how that should work or I'm just to stupid.

thanks in advance